# Reuse raw pointer to rehydrate Rust Box

Tags: rust

I have a function that coverts a `Box::into_raw` result into a `u64`. I later 're-`Box`' with from the `u64`.

```
// Somewhere at inception
let bbox = Box::new(MyStruct::from_u32(1u32).unwrap());
let rwptr = Box::into_raw(bbox);
let bignum_ptr = rwptr as u64;

// Later in life
let rehyrdrate: Box<MyStruct> = unsafe {
    Box::from_raw(bignum_ptr as *mut MyStruct)
};
```

What I would like to do is 're-`Box`' that `bignum_ptr` again, and again, as needed. Is this possible?

Comment: What should happen when `rehydrate` goes out of scope? Should the memory allocated for the box be freed or not?

Comment: The holder of `bignum_ptr` would be responsible for dropping,

Comment: In that case `rehydrate` should be a _reference_, not a box: `let rehyrdrate: &MyStruct = unsafe { &*(bignum_ptr as *const MyStruct) };`. When you need to free the box (and know that no outstanding references exist), you can use `drop(Box::from_raw(bignum_ptr as *mut MyStruct))`.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks... I will give that a try!

Comment: There should rarely be any reason to cast a raw pointer to an integer, but if you have to (some FFIs require it), you should use `usize` instead of `u64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A box owns the data it points to, and will deallocate/drop it when it goes out of scope, so if you need use the same pointer in more than one place, `Box` is not the correct type. To support multiple "revivals" of the pointer, you can use a reference instead:

```
// safety contract: bignum_ptr comes from a valid pointer, there are no
// mutable references
let rehydrate: &MyStruct = unsafe { &*(bignum_ptr as *const MyStruct) };
```

When the time comes to free the initial box and its data (and you know that no outstanding references exist), only then re-create the box using `Box::from_raw`:

```
// safety contract: bignum_ptr comes from a valid pointer, no references
// of any kind remain
drop(unsafe { Box::from_raw(bignum_ptr as *const MyStruct) });
```

Comment: As I mention in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66564860/9305398), it isn't guaranteed that one can round-trip via an integer; it might or might not be guaranteed in the future, but we don't know yet, even if it happens to work now. In general, there are very few reasons to convert a pointer to an integer anyway.

Comment: @Acorn This code breaking would break **a lot** of other code (including virtually all FFI), so unless you can come up with specific references in the context of Rust, I do not find your answer relevant. The part I do agree with is the assumption that pointer fits into `u64`; I'd use `usize` instead.

Comment: Also, the roundtrip through u64 is just a minor part of the question, the main point of the question and the answer ownership-related. Remarks on the u64 roundtrip probably belongs in comments to the question, not here.

Comment: This code breaking does **not** mean FFI code would necessarily break. The burden is on you to come up with one saying this *is* sound, since this is your answer. At any rate, this language area is still being designed, so one cannot tell one way or the other, which is the problem.

Comment: Re: round-trip via an integer is not a minor point at all, since it can make this whole affair unsound. The question points quite clearly this is done via `u64` in the very first sentence.

Comment: @Acorn It's a minor point for this answer because the same solution ("rehydrate" by creating a reference rather than a new box) would apply if the cast to `u64` were omitted from the question.

Comment: No, it wouldn't apply, because we are discussing unsafe code.

Comment: @Acorn The OP's issue had to do with the ownership of the `Box`, not with the cast to `u64`. The solution from this answer addresses the ownership issue and is orthogonal to the casting. Not only would the solution apply to the question modified to omit the cast, but it would apply _better_ because the problem you raise (pointer provenance) wouldn't exist to begin with.

Comment: To me, it looks like OP needs to know whether the construction is sound or not; and answering that requires talking about it as a whole. At any rate, even if it was sound, telling someone to create multiple references from a pointer and manage them themselves is *really* asking for trouble. Why does one want to use Rust, at that point? It is safer, in fact, to use C to play such games. OP should recreate the original `Box` and then grab multiple references from it, instead.

Comment: @user4815162342 - Quick follow up... how would I 're-hydrate' to a mutable reference to MyStruct?

Comment: @FrankC. Note that mutable references have more stringent requirements - you may not have more than one active at the same time pointing to the same data. Having said that, their creation is essentially the same, just use `*mut` and `&mut` instead of `*const` and `&`.

Answer (score -1):

> What I would like to do is 're-Box' that bignum_ptr again, and again, as needed. Is this possible?

If you mean creating many boxes from the same pointer without taking it out each time, no.

If you mean putting it in and out repeatedly and round-tripping every time via an integer, probably yes; however, I would be careful with code like that. Most likely, it will work, but be aware that the memory model for Rust is not formalized and the rules around pointer provenance may change in the future. Even the C and C++ standards (from where Rust memory model comes from) have open questions around those, including round-tripping via an integer type.

Furthermore, your code assumes a pointer fits in a `u64`, which is likely true for most architectures, but maybe not all in the future.

At the very least, I suggest you use `mem::transmute` rather than a cast.

---

In short: don't do it. There is likely a better design for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That kind of code (modulo the lifetime issue discussed in the comments) must be supported in some form for FFI to work. Sending a raw pointer to an extern C function and back is equivalent to the above.

Comment: @user4815162342 Normally, you would send pointers via `*mut` and `*const`, not via an integer. Even if an integer is used, Rust could allow it for FFI yet disallow "local" round-tripping via an integer type.

Comment: @Acorn - Understood... the application of this is for blockchain so in the near term it is not an issue